# Weird screen artifacts - BTT PITFT50 V2.0

Tags: touchscreen

I have brand new Raspberry Pi 4B and a Beetreetech PiTFT50 Touch screen.

It's connected via the flat flex cable in the back.  The first time I plugged it in I noticed that there where some vertical lines present on the bootup screen where the white bold text was displayed.  The lines slowly dissipate when the screen is still.  I have a [video of the boot process](https://bitless.be/img/VID_20220914_071420.mp4) showing it.

[image]

At that moment, I didn't take care of the drivers yet, I'm using the mainsail image but it's also present in the standard Pi installation on a second SD card.

After manipulating the screen a bit, installing drivers, taking care of the configuration and installing Klipperscreen (having it running for a while too) they where gone and I didn't give it any more thoughts.  After it has been running for about a week with no issues, perfect screen I put it in a 3D printed case.

yesterday, they came back.  I'm suspecting that the flat cable might have an issue so I reseated it a few times carefully but I can't seem to get rid of it now.

[image]

I could use some suggestions here, I ordered a set of new 15pin cables to make sure.  The boot rainbow screen seems to be fine however afaik.

Does anyone seen this before, can it be the cable?  Or would this new screen be defective ?  Which would suck as it's an Aliexpress thing.  It was well wrapped in the typical BTT box.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me. It's so weird the way it flows, it's hard to explain so I made a video to support the question.

**EDIT**: Contacted the manufacturer, they agreed it's a hardware problem, probably some bad soldering I think.  They were quite nice in fact, didn't took them too long to commit to sending a new screen which I received a tracking nr for this week.

New cables didn't solve this either, got 10 of them and tried 5, so pretty sure it's not the cable either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a hardware problem, I've got a replacement on the way from China. So far they have been very helpful.  No discussions, just well documented from my part which probably helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem as you described. Have you got it sorted yet?

I can't find much info on the net. I only received my BigTreeTech screen yesterday and I'm wondering should I get in touch with the seller in case it's a screen issue or is it more to do with drivers and/or configuration.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question , it's indeed a hardware issue.   I would recommend contacting the supplier too.   I've tried everything,  since it's for a 3D printer, I've tested several different Pi images with different drivers to no avail.   Hope this helps